# Rails how to create cookies and call data later?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I create cookies in Rails?

Example a user visit:

```
http://mywebsite.com/ref/stackowerflow
```

Then I want to safe `stackowerflow`

And call it later example

`<%= ref %>` Output: `stackowerflow`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creating cookie (preferably in controller):

```
cookies[:referer] = "stackoverflow"
```

Creating cookie that expires in an hour:

```
cookies[:referer] = { :value => "stackoverflow", :expires => Time.now + 1.hour}
```

Reading cookie:

```
ref = cookies[:referer] # "stackoverflow"
```

Deleting cookie:

```
cookies.delete :referer
```

Comment: What other values are there possiable to read. Example created_at. Should the cookie be encrypted?

Comment: https://github.com/hmcfletch/encrypted-cookie-store encrypted cookies are ok, but it all depends on data sensitivity. For most secure, please use SSL. You can store objects in value: `cookies[:referer] = { :value => { :referer => 'stackoverflow', :created_at => Time.now } }`

Comment: It should be as easy as working with hash object in ruby. `cookies[:referer] = "something_else"` or cookies[:referer][:value] = {:foo => "bar"}`